# Book error: パパは銀行に出かけていていないよ

Tags: word-usage

There is this phrase
パパは銀行に出かけていていないよ
And the given translation is
Your dad has gone to the bank.

But here I think it is a negation instead. Which is correct?

Answer (score 13):

Grammatically, there are two predicates in this sentence, (銀行に)出かけている and いない.

- **銀行に出かけている**: "has gone to the bank", "is out at the bank"
- **いない**: "is not here", "is away"

> パパは銀行に出かけていて、いないよ。
> <sup>(Added comma for clarity)</sup>
>
> (literally) Dad has gone to the bank, and is away.
>
> Dad is not here, (because) he's out at the bank.

パパは銀行に出かけていないよ would be a single-predicate negative sentence, "Dad has not gone to the bank (i.e., he is at home)".

Comment: 出かけていていない <-- would anyone actually say this in real life? To my non-native ear it sounds rather clumsy and confusing.

Comment: @user3856370 If there is a sufficient pause, yes. If it were said without a pause, it would be very confusing.